# Displaying Current User Info on Login

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to display the current user info when only they are logged in..
I have got the users info to display but it displays all users not just the logged in user. it is showing all users

```
<?php
        $sql = "SELECT users.uid, users.username, user_images.user_image
        FROM users, user_images
        WHERE users.user_id = users.user_id";

        $result = query($sql);
        while (($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) != false) {

            $uid = $row['uid'];
            $user_image = $row['user_image'];
            $username = $row['username'];


            echo "$username";
            echo "$user_image";

        }        
 ?>
```

> My Login

```
function login_user($email, $password)
{
    $sql = "SELECT user_pwd, uid FROM users WHERE user_email = '" . escape($email) . "' AND active = 1";

    $result = query($sql);

    if (row_count($result) == 1) {

        $row = fetch_array($result);

        $db_password = $row['user_pwd'];

        if (password_verify($password, $db_password)) {

            $_SESSION['email'] = $email;            

            return true;
        } else {

            return false;
        }

        return true;
    } else {

        return false;
    }
}
```

> Query Functions

```
function row_count($result)
{
    return mysqli_num_rows($result);
}


function query($query)
{
    global $connection;
    return mysqli_query($connection, $query);
}


function fetch_array($result)
{
    global $connection;
    return mysqli_fetch_array($result);
}
```

Comment: Have you used session in your login?Your query should be `users.user_id = userSession`.

Comment: Where is the current user id stored? Sessions?

Comment: @PhiterFernandes current user id is stored in the database.

Comment: Where do you store the information when he logs in?

Comment: @PhiterFernandes I added code of my login up above no sessions are stored anywhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your login you should create a session variable for userid

```
 function login_user($email, $password)
    {
        $sql = "SELECT user_pwd, uid FROM users WHERE user_email = '" . escape($email) . "' AND active = 1";

        $result = query($sql);

        if (row_count($result) == 1) {

            $row = fetch_array($result);

            $db_password = $row['user_pwd'];

            if (password_verify($password, $db_password)) {

                $_SESSION['email'] = $email;            
                $_SESSION['user_id'] = $row['user_id'];
                return true;
            } else {

                return false;
            }

            return true;
        } else {

            return false;
        }
    }
```

then in the php file where you want to display the users info you will use **`$_SESSION['user_id']`**

```
<?php
        session_start();
        $user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
        $sql = "SELECT users.uid, users.username, user_images.user_image
        FROM users, user_images
        WHERE users.user_id = {$user_id}";

        $result = query($sql);
        while (($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) != false) {

            $uid = $row['uid'];
            $user_image = $row['user_image'];
            $username = $row['username'];


            echo "$username";
            echo "$user_image";

        }        
 ?>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: if I login works great if I logout I get 2 errors  Notice: Undefined variable: uid

Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given

Comment: can you post your query function in your post??

Comment: I did james its at the top

Comment: is your `users.user_id` is a varchar or text datatype?

Comment: I figured out what is causing the error on my profile page I have a navigation include what I was trying to do is get the user name to show in the nav bar that's whats causing the error

Comment: sort of ok so I have the code updated I have a navigation that is a included what can I use to call the username to the navigation bar since its a include

Comment: james I have a nav.php included in my profile page how can I grab that session username and put it in the nav bar?

Comment: you can use it directly in your profile page.if you have included it in the profile page.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the query in the where clause :

```
$sql = "SELECT users.uid, users.username, user_images.user_image
        FROM users, user_images
        WHERE users.user_id = users.user_id";
```

equate `users.user_id` to current logged in user id.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean sandy?

Comment: Where did you store the current logged in user id? In any session variable?